# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll: 'Value cannot be null.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, desktop-application, serilog, microsoft-extensions-logging

This is my Program.cs class

```
 private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
 {  
         var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .WriteTo.File("TheCodeBuzz.txt")
           .CreateLogger();

            services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                builder.AddSerilog(logger: serilogLogger, dispose: true);
            });

}
```

And This is My MainForm.cs as I am designing a desktop application

```
partial class MainForm : IDisposable
{
     private readonly ILogger _logger;

     public MainForm(ILogger logger)
     {           
          _logger = logger;
     }

     private void Hello()
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("message");
     }
}
```

_logger.LogInformation throws a run time error i.e. An unhandled exception

Comment: `ILogger` is not registered with the service collection by default. You should use `ILogger<MainForm>` instead.

Comment: Hie, @Martin Costello. It is giving a fatal error for type conversion at a constructor

Comment: @DhruviParikh - you also need to define the member field as `private readonly ILogger<MainForm> _logger;`.

Comment: I am getting a type cast error in the constructor

Comment: Hi @DhruviParikh, both your `_logger` field and constructor parameter `logger` need change type `ILogger` to `ILogger<MainForm>`.